# NFS partition not mounted automatically at boot time anymore

Tags: mount, fstab, 14.10, nfs

In Ubuntu 14.04, I was auto-mounting my NAS partition using NFS by adding the following line in my /etc/fstab:

```
192.168.1.100:/volume1/Downloads        /home/pierre/Downloads_NAS      nfs     rsize=8192,wsize=8192,timeo=14,intr
```

As a result, I could access my NAS in Nautilus directly after booting up.

I upgraded to Ubuntu 14.10, and I can no longer access it after booting up. When trying to access the folder, I have the following error:

```
**Unable to access “Downloads_NAS”**
mount: only root can mount 192.168.1.100:/volume1/Downloads on /home/pierre/Downloads_NAS
```

if I open a term and run

```
% sudo mount 192.168.1.100:/volume1/Downloads /home/pierre/Downloads_NAS
```

Then I can access it normally.

What can I do to mount the partition automatically at boot time?

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure if this works with `nfs` mounting, but try adding `user` to the options in the `/etc/fstab` line. First, unmount it, then edit the options so they look like this: `rsize=8192,wsize=8192,timeo=14,intr,user`, then run `mount -a` and check if it works.

Comment: Awesome! this has been bugging me for ages!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As proposed by @AlaaAli, I just needed to add `user` to the option of the mount in the `etc/fstab`:

`192.168.1.100:/volume1/Downloads        /home/pierre/Downloads_NAS      nfs     rsize=8192,wsize=8192,timeo=14,intr,user`

Now the partition is automatically mounted when needed.

Answer (score 0):

Use the GUI Disk utility come with Ubuntu. The software is named "Disks"

1. Select the partition in the dashboard.
2. Click settings button under the dashboard.
3. Select Edit Mount Options
4. Turn off the Automatic Mount Options toggle. Then it will show the options.
5. Check the Mount at startup if not checked.
6. Click safe. Remember the mount point.

You're done. Congratulations.